# Merge all files in directory by column

Tags: macos, csv, command-line, header, copy-paste

I have hundreds of .ASC files that I would like to combine into a single file via Mac OSX command line.

The file type isn't hugely important, a code that works for .csv files would be useful too.

Let's pretend I have three files:

Each file looks like:

header 1_file1

header 2 

header 3

header 4

header 5

a

b

c

d

e

I want the data to look like:

header 1_file1    header 1_file2    header 1_file3

header 2    header 2    header 2 

header 3    header 3    header 3 

header 4    header 4    header 4 

header 5    header 5    header 5 

a    a    a

b    b    b

c    c    c

d    d    d

e    e    e

I tried

paste -d ',' *.ASC ... > merge.csv

But this resulted in a merged file that looked like this (pretend I merged 3 files):

Header 1_file1

Header 1_file2

Header 1_file3

Header 2

Header 2

Header 2

Header 3

Header 3

Header 3

etc. etc.

What can I do? Thanks in advance for your help.